# How to pass an EAV value to the Paypal payment information

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.9

I've introduced a custom EAV attribute for the customer object. Let's call it myvalue. Within several places in magento, I'm printing the value like this:

```
echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getMyvalue();
```

When the customer pays with paypal, I'd like to have `myvalue` in the reason as an addition to the order number. My intent is to match the order with some shop-side process.

So, how can I pass `myvalue` to paypal to make it visible together with the order number?

Comment: What Paypal method are you using?

Comment: It's Paypal Standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to override the class `Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect` into something like this:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $standard = Mage::getModel('paypal/standard');

    //...

    foreach ($standard->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() as $field=>$value) {
        if ($field == 'REASON_CODE') {
            $myvalue = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getMyvalue();
            $value .= $myvalue;
        }
        $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$value));
    }

    //...

    return $html;
}
```

I have added a condition in the foreach to edit the reason with your special customer value.

I don't know what is the code for the reason you speak about, if you don't as well you can first log that in the foreach:

```
Mage::log($field);
Mage::log($value);
```

Then don't forget to edit `'REASON_CODE'` and `getCustomer()->getMyvalue()` in my example.